# Forbid ajax calls in some parts of the code

Tags: javascript, ajax

For our internal js framework, to ensure good usage of the framework, I want to forbid the usage of Ajax requests in some parts of the framework.

Is there a way to achieve something similar to this:

```
function doSomething() {

  instructions with ajax calls...

  withAjaxForbidden(function() {
     instructions using ajax calls should raise exception here
  });

  instructions with ajax calls...

}
```

Is it possible to implement something like `withAjaxForbidden`?

Note that obviously I expect the ajax system to be leaved in a consistent state in case an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own ajax function and make it dependent on some global variable. After that you can just remove the regular ajax functions from the scope and you're done :)

```
var ajaxEnabled = true;

function withAjaxForbidden(f){
    ajaxEnabled = false;
    f();
    ajaxEnabled = true;
}

function ajax(...){
    if(!ajaxEnabled)throw 'Ajax requests are forbidden within this block';
    ...
}
```

Here's a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/u98b7bk3/1/

```
<div id="console">
    No messages yet
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Disable Ajax globally, to keep it working for your own library make
    // sure you save this locally before overwriting
    XMLHttpRequest = undefined;
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Try an ajax request with jQuery
    $.ajax('/').always(function(data, status, error){
        $('#console').html("data: " + data + "<br>status: " + status + "<br>error: " + error);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this does not prevent usages of ajax that we can't modify, like using an external library that will not be wired to that ajax function. And it does not leave in a consistent state in case an error is thrown imo

Comment: @SebastienLorber: yes it does if you remove the regular ajax functions from the scope like I mentioned :)

Comment: If these `regular ajax calls` are done inside library dependencies, I have to modify the libraries to replace the regular ajax calls from my own ajax function so it's not what I'm looking for (and the point of my first comment). If you still think you are right please give an exemple with a library dependency that does XHR calls

Comment: @SebastienLorber: I've added an example

Comment: Modifying a global variable (especially native) could have unexpected results. Please see my answer as a safer alternative :)

Comment: @JonathanGray: Although I agree, your solution won't disable external libraries from working which is what Sebastien wants. Naturally this code should not be run in a production environment :)

Comment: It could handle third party libraries with some modification

Comment: @Wolph For example, to handle JQuery the $ global variable just needs to be recreated within the lexical scope without the AJAX-related methods. That could be done with a loop and blacklist object.

Comment: @JonathanGray: My point is that it won't work out of the box if someone installs/links a different library. You would have to create a patch for every library separately.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it will work in cases where the library keeps a handle to the XMLHttpRequest object. If you change the XMLHttpRequest object before the library makes a handle to it then it will end up keeping a handle to your object. So short of completely recreating your own version of XMLHttprequest, I think that would be the best way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables override global variables within the function's scope. Simply create a variable for each native and library ajax function and set it to undefined from within your protected function. It will be prevented from being able to make use of the functions and variables by the same name. As long as they are set using "var" it should only affect the function's scope and not the global scope.

Edit: This may not be exactly what you were looking for, but as far as I know the precise way you want to accomplish this is not possible due to variable scoping but if you don't mind the extra code around your AJAX-restricted code you can use this method. Unlike the other answer this will work asynchronously and does *not* affect global variables, which makes it much less likely that problems will occur from the use of this code:

Edit 2 (with jQuery support):

```
var testFunction = (function($){
    // Global to local/lexical:
    var XMLHttpRequest = undefined;
    var eval = undefined;
    var setTimeout = undefined;
    var setInterval = undefined;
    var Function = undefined;
    var window = undefined;
    $ = (function($){ if($) {
        var newjq = function(s, c) {
            // Reroute main function
            return $(s, c);
            };
        var jQueryBlacklist = {
            // Initialize blacklist
            "ajax": true,
            "post": true,
            "get": true,
            "getJSON": true,
            "getScript": true
            };
        for(i in $) // Reconstruct Object
         if($.hasOwnProperty(i)
         && !jQueryBlacklist[i])
          newjq[i] = $[i];
        return newjq;
        } }($));
    // Real testFunction() below:
    return function() {
        // AJAX-forbidden code
        // $.ajax should be undefined
        }
    }($));
// $.ajax should work normally here
testFunction(); // not in here
// $.ajax should work normally here
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhxq9goa/2/) to see the fiddle